# xfce and icewm - window manager configuration file doesn't work

Tags: x11, xfce, icewm

I would like to replace a default xfce windowmanager (xfwm4) with icewm. 
I have installed the following package using apt: icewm.

In the file: `/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml`
 xfwm4 is replaced with icewm. I have created a file winoptions (touch winoptions) in the directory `~/.icewm`. The file contains the following line:

```
testApp1.SimpleGL.geometry: 500x1000+300+0
```

where testApp1 is a window class and SimpleGL is a window title. A window manager starts but the config file has no effect when I start a defined window. What might be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: I just saw that you try to call icewm from xfce. It's not option, icewm is a full desktop environment itself. Update your `~/.xinitrc` with `exec icewm-session` at last line.

If you use debian based distro, you can symlink icewm-session to `/etc/alternatives/x-session-manager` via `update-alternatives --config x-session-manager`.

---

The first part is enough of WM_CLASS, but you can use both. Easiest way to find it: `xprop WM_CLASS` then click inside the window. For example:

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "leafpad", "Leafpad"
```

Then use this in `~/.icewm/winoptions` :

```
leafpad.Leafpad.geometry: 640x480+100+100
leafpad.Leafpad.workspace: 2
```

This is my currently working setting, i've tested it now. Hint: You can reload icewm settings any time with: `killall -HUP icewm`

Comment: Ok, in your example "leafpad" is a window class and "Leafpad" is a window title, but why those values come from WM_CLASS (a window title is stored in WM_NAME). For my window xprop shows:  WM_CLASS(STRING) = "testApp1", "testApp1" and title is here: WM_NAME(STRING) = "SimpleGL"